# Study the existence and uniqueness of the following O.D.E.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to study the the existence and uniqueness of solution for the function:
$$f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}; ~~ f(t,x) = \begin{cases}
   -1 ,& x<0, \\ 
 ~~ 0, &x=0, \\ 
 ~~ 1,& x>0.
\end{cases}
$$ 
Since $\mathbb{R}×\mathbb{R}$ is open, but $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$, I can't say whether a solution exists or not.

After that I need to study the uniqueness and existence of a solution for this function but this  time on $\mathbb{R}×\mathbb{R}^*$.

P.S. I am learning the Peano and Cauchy-Lipschitz theorems for uniqueness and existence of solution. Since these theorems are not very clear to me I would very much appreciate a detailed solution for my problem. Thank you.

Comment: I wonder where has this phantom ODE disappeared ?

Answer (score 0):

The equation $\dot x=sign(x)$ has a solution $x(t)=0$ for $x_0=0$ and all $t$, and $x(t)=x_0+sign(x_0)t$ for $x_0\ne 0$ and $|t|<|x_0|$, thus is locally solvable with unique solutions but not necessarily continuity of the solutions relative to the initial value.